# how to alter an auto increment primary key in table in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a two tables,in which i have a table having **a primary key given property** **auto increment**.So if i alter the table by deleting a row  and updated the table.But still the Key value is not changed.next input will be stored in consecutive value:

*For eg*

```
create table Student
(
regid int primary key auto_increment not null
)
```

regid here is the primary key,i also have a foreign key in another table.
But if insert a data into this and later deleted it(say row where `regid=5`),my next input has a regid value 6 even if the 5 one is deleted..
Help me solve this

Comment: Add your code, your trials so far

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` assigns incremental values but does not prevent gaps or reuse previously assigned values.

Comment: create table student (regid int primary key auto_increment not null,fname varchar (120) not null default 'no name',dob date not null default '0000-00-00',courseid int,foreign key(courseid) references course(cid));

create table course(cid int not null auto_increment primary key,cname varchar(200) not null default 'no name',cduration int not null default 0);

insert into student(fname,dob,courseid) values('name1''1990-02-02',1);

insert into course(cname,cduration) values('mysql',4);

Answer (score 0):

This is the auto_increment property so it will start from next till either you truncate table (start from 1) or set your choice auto_increment by alter as per below-

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Comment: so each time we update or alter the table we need to alter the auto_increment value also??

Comment: actually you don't need to change auto_increment value as what matter if it is 5 or 6...just matter that it should be correctly mapped with child table.